# Can i create a sql table populated with Salesforce objects?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

does Salesforce offer a way to obtain all Objects like Account, Contact etc and populate them in a SQL table with certain columns like 
ObjectEntity, FieldName , FieldType ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the only way to achieve this would be by using the `Schema.sObjectType` and `Schema.sObjectField`. [Here is a link to the documentation for getting all sObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_global_describe.htm). You will basically call the `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` method which will return you a map of sObjectTypes with their sObject name as the key. Then you'll need to call `getDesribe()` on each sObjectType get the fields of the object from that Describe result. You'll again need to call `getDescribe()` on each sObjectField in order to have access to the columns you wanted (eg. FieldType). [Here is the documentation on that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_methods_system_fields_describe)  You could save each DescribeFieldResult into a list that goes into a Map of > with the sObject name as the key, then you could do what you want with them... Put them in a table if you like. Keep in mind this is all going to be very expensive when it comes to CPU time. You may even run into some governor limits. 
Here is a little example you can run using *Execute Anonymous* in the developer console where the sObject Name and all its field names and types are printed to  the debug logs

```java
Map<String, sObjectType> objects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
for(String objName : objects.keySet()){
    system.debug('=======' + objName + '=========\n Fields: ');
    sObjectType o = objects.get(objName);
    DescribeSobjectResult oDRes = o.getDescribe();
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = dResult.fields.getMap();
    for(Schema.SObjectField f : fields.values()){
        DescribeFieldResult fDRes = f.getDescribe();
        system.debug('name: ' + fDRes.getName() + ' | type: ' + fDRes.getType());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This can bring back all required fields , but for example in the Account object the required fields returned are IsDeleted, Name and Id. But all that is required in order to create an Account object is just the Name field. So is it possible to return only the required fields to create the object. It is like in the Salesforce Ui, when you click on new to create the object , only the name field has a red border , meaning it is the minimum required field in order to create the Account , not all 3 fields are required., so I guess mandatory fields ? Can this be done programmatically as well ?

Comment: @Mel I see. I'm not 100% sure but I would look at the method isDefaultedOnCreate()

In the DescribeFieldResult documentation In the second link above. You may be able to use this to filter out fields like isDeleted and Id as I'd assume these come under defaulted on create fields

Comment: Hi , yes I managed to use the method isDefaultedOnCreate(). The whole purpose of this is that I am trying to get the SObject and create Apex Unit tests. But I need to dynamically create them. So for example Account all I need is the Name field. But for something like Contract I need Status, StartDate, ContractTerm , and AccountId (which) links to an Account object. So I need to create an Account object first and link the contract object to that. In essence I am trying to pass in an Object name to a procedure and from that create a test.

Comment: Ah I see the contact account link would be hard but you can check the field type for lookup relationship/master-detail and if it is move up and create that object with its mandatory fields than set it on the child object. It's a great idea test data is always annoying to create manually